# UniqueID binding in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate the functionality of the [Unique Name](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/uniqueName-binding.html) binding for an element's ID (to get [pretty validation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) working)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueID = {
   'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            element.ID = "ko_unique_" + (++ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'].currentIndex);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The knockout source for uniqueName is

```
ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            element.name = "ko_unique_" + (++ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'].currentIndex);

            // Workaround IE 6 issue - http://www.matts411.com/post/setting_the_name_attribute_in_ie_dom/
            if (ko.utils.isIe6)
                element.mergeAttributes(document.createElement("<input name='" + element.name + "'/>"), false);
        }
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'].currentIndex = 0;
```

So I think you should have this (note ID should be id, IE6 stuff removed, and uniqueName changed to uniqueId)

```
ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueId'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            element.id = "ko_unique_" + (++ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueId'].currentIndex);           
        }
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueId'].currentIndex = 0;
```