# Dynamic ID in KnockoutJS code block

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, knockout.js

I've done some research on the subject, but I couldn't find anything really useful for this.

**My problem**:

> I have a list of Items(in SharePoint) and I am using KnockoutJS
>   foreach statement to display a table with all of them.  Like this:
>
> Quantity  |   Price   |   Total_Price |  RadioButton1  | RadioButton2
>
> As you can see there are 2 radio buttons and it is mandatory to use an id attribute for them ( because I am also using JqueryUI - *label for='id of element'* - )

I tried something like this >

Example of code:

.....

> <% int i=1; %>
>    < ! - -  ko foreach: Items -->    
>                         ........
>
> ```
>      <input type="radio" id="Yes+<%=i %>"/>
>      <label for="Yes+<%=i %>" >Yes</label>
>      <input type="radio" id="No+<%=i %>" />
>      <label for="No+<%=i %>">No</label>
>
>      </td>
> ```
>
> <%i++; %>
>
> > < !-- /ko -->

The thing is asp code does not recognize ko foreach iterations.

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: You can use the KO uniqueid binding suggested in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259999/uniqueid-binding-in-knockout

Comment: And how can I put this on  input id

Comment: You could use the index of the item if you wanted to.

Comment: something like this ? data-bind="attr: { id: $index()}"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you put an Id on the Item viewmodel then use that?

```
< ! - - ko foreach: Items --> ........

 <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { id: 'Yes' + Id }" />
 <label data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'Yes' + Id }" >Yes</label>
 <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { id: 'No' + Id } />
 <label data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'No' + Id }">No</label>

 </td>
< !-- /ko -->
```

or use the index observable as Macropus suggested:

```
< ! - - ko foreach: Items --> ........

 <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { id: 'Yes' + $index() }" />
 <label data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'Yes' + $index() }" >Yes</label>
 <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { id: 'No' + $index() } />
 <label data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'No' + $index() }">No</label>

 </td>
< !-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Yes. I'll use what Macropus suggested and if it's not working I'll modify the view model.

Comment: I believe you need to use $index() instead of $index, since it is observable.

Comment: I've also enclosed the "for" in single quotes.  Although it works without, for is a reserved JavaScript keyword and it's probably safer to escape it

Comment: In the top example the observable Id is used to differentiate between iterations. However, as it is written it does not work. You need to use Id() to get the value, just as was done with $index() below.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are just using this for labels, you can use the knockout uniqueid binding in this post:

[UniqueID binding in knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259999/uniqueid-binding-in-knockout)

There is also a uniquename binding